# Blazor, can't get embedded component to refresh

Tags: webassembly, blazor

I realize this isn't a released product so I'm just experimenting, hopefully some of you came across a solution to the problem I am experiencing.

I have Component `B` included in Component `A`. When an item in a `list` is selected, Component `B` sees that and loads and displays the necessary data.

However, when I select another item from the **combo** `list` from Component `A`, it will not refresh component B's `list` and I guess that is because `OnInitAsync` is not called subsequently.

Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: This is hard to tell without any code, could you please include that?

Comment: Also, are you following this pattern for binding between components: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/610 ?

Comment: Yes I'm following that pattern.. That is the passing of parameters. From these paramters the ChildComponent is able to load data from a backend web api in the OnInitAsync. After, when I change one of these parameters, new data needs tobe loading from the backend web api and part of the problem is that OnInitAsync was already loaded. I tried to move that to a function and call it from the view, making it async but that didn't help much.. I need to first hide the component and show it again in order for it to call OnInitAsync.

Comment: I'll try and get some code but, that will be difficult since it is not code I can really show without modifying it a bit..

Comment: I actually found what I need to do. The BlazorComponent comes with a function called StateHasChanged(). When the component has already been drawn and something changes, you can request for it to redraw itself by calling that function and it all works out.

Comment: Ok, nice. Please add it as the answer.

Comment: But how would component B know that its parameters has changed so I can call StateHasChanged?

Answer (score 2):

For everybody not reading the comments, the solution was to call `StateHasChanged()` at the correct moment.

At sometime in development of blazor this requirement should be fulfilled automatically by the framework. See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/699)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar case where Component A had to select a Value that should Referesh Component B options, B was a child component of A

in Component B use this method, and pass there selected value as parameter

```
protected override async void OnParametersSet()
    {
        await getLookupListAsync();
    }
```